# Store and retrieve objects after using post form

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am building the section of my e commerce in Flask where customers can choose one of many shipping services alternatives. Building the options for the `SelectField` is expensive since I have to query and call different APIs from shipping providers to get quotes. After the POST request is sent and I have a selection from my customer, I would like to avoid having to rebuild all the objects, including the company, service, and price. What would be the best approach in this case? I understand `g` nor `session` would serve me in this case, and I would really like to avoid having to write options to the database. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `session` to store the three pieces of information?

Comment: It's not just three pieces of info, I would need to store a lists of info. I can only store strings in the session dictionary, right?